# Perl regular expression to match the first instance of ? across multiple lines

Tags: regex, perl, matching, multiline

I am trying to parse an e-mail reply using regular expressions. My response looks like:

```
This is my response.
Some text here

?



?



From: Lastname, Firstname

Sent: Saturday, January 05, 2013 7:37 PM

To: Lastname, Firstname

Subject: Some Subject



?



Some Text
```

I am interested in parsing everything up to the first ?. 
I have tried utilizing single line mode with `$response =~ /^(.*)\?\n/s;`. But that returns me everything up to the last ?. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

`.*` is greedy. The non-greedy version `.*?` should work.

Answer (score 4):

By far the most efficient way to do this is with a negated character class:

```
 while ($response =~ / ( [^?]* \? ) /xg) { ... }
```

Comment: Screw efficiency, this is more reliable and maintainable than non-greedy modifiers. e.g. Adding to the pattern won't break this bit.

Answer (score 1):

You need non-greedy mode for the `.*`:

```
$response =~ /^(.*?)\?\n/s
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not neccesarry to do it with ungreedy expressions. You can match all text to the first line starting with `?` via

```
/^((?:(?!^\?).)*)/sm
```

if you only want to match the first `?` do it with

```
/^([^?]*(?=\?))/s
```

Comment: I have no idea the reason for the downvote — it was not mine — but I would encourage you to benchmark this and the other solutions provided by others against inputs varying significantly in length and composition. You may be surprised by how slow the lookahead solution can become.